# Como cambiar el tamaño de un array dinamico en C despues de eliminar un elemento?

Tags: c, manejo-de-memoria

Estoy creando un array a traves de la funcion calloc alojando 5 espacios de memoria que luego el usuario llena con numeros. Por ejemplo quedaria {1,2,3,4,5}.

Si uno de esos elemento es borrado/reemplazado por 0 quedando por ejemplo {1,2,0,4,5} como puedo usar la funcion realloc para cambiar el tamaño del array de manera que solo queden los numeros restantes?

Deberia quedar asi {1,2,4,5}.

```
int main()
{
    int sizeArray = 5;
    int listaNumeros[sizeArray];
    int* pArray = NULL;


    pArray = listaNumeros;

    crearArray(pArray,sizeArray);
    llenarDatos(pArray,sizeArray);
    mostrarArray(pArray,sizeArray);

    return 0;
}

void crearArray(int* array, int tam)
{
   if(array != NULL)
   {
     array = (int*)calloc(sizeof(int),tam);
   }
}

void borrarElement(int* array, int tam)
{
    int indice;
    int i;

    if(array != NULL)
    {
        printf("Indice a borrar: ");
        scanf("%d", &indice);
        for(i=0;i<tam;i++)
        {
            if(*(array+i) == indice)
            {
                *(array+i) = 0;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: ¿Que código tienes hecho hasta ahora con respecto a la función borrar elemento? Debes agregarlo a la pregunta..

Comment: Ahi agregue, por el momento solo la modifico a 0

Comment: Realmente no necesitas redimensionar el array cada vez que vas a eliminar un elemento. Simplemente debes establecer una capacidad inicial y al momento de añadir elementos, verificas que la cantidad de elementos actuales no sobrepase la capacidad máxima que hayas establecido, si lo hace, ahí redimensionas el arreglo usando realloc.

Comment: Si haces lo que te digo, seria sencillo implementar una función que borre un elemento, porque solo debes desplazar los elementos de izquierda a derecha. Por ejemplo, si los elementos son 1  3  8  12  20  25, ... y quiero eliminar el número 8, debo desplazar el número 12 en la posición donde estaba el 8, luego desplazar el 20 donde estaba antes el 12 y así sucesivamente.. De este modo es como puedes quitar el elemento de la lista. Así es como funciona la clase ArrayList de Java por ejemplo.